# Integral involving square of associated Laguerre polynomial and sperical bessel function

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, integration, special-functions

In a quantum mechanical problem I encountered the integral
$$I_k=\int_0^\infty x^{2(l+1)-k}j_k(\sigma x)e^{-x}[L_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}(x)]^2 dx,$$
where $j_k(x)$ is a spherical Bessel function, and $\sigma$ is a real parameter.

Using the following entry from Gradshtein and Ryzhik (p. 858)
$$\int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{-bx}L_n^\alpha(\lambda x) L_m^\alpha(\mu x)dx=
\frac{\Gamma(m+n+\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(m+1)\;\Gamma(n+1)}\frac{(b-\lambda)^n(b-\mu)^m}{b^{m+n+\alpha+1}}\;F\left (-m,-n;-m-n-\alpha;\frac{b(b-\lambda-\mu)}{(b-\mu)(b-\lambda)}\right ),$$
and some properties of the hypergeometric function $F$, we can get
$$I_0=\frac{2(n+l)!}{(n-l-1)!}\frac{\cos^{2l+4}(\phi)\;\sin{(2n\phi)}}{\sin{(2\phi)}}P_{\;n-l-1}^{(0,\;2l+1)}(\cos{(2\phi)}),$$
where $\tan{\phi}=\sigma$, and $P_{\;n-l-1}^{(0,\;2l+1)}(x)$ are Jacobi polynomials. Can this result be generalized for non-zero $k$?

Comment: Due to the recurrence relations https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.51.i the function $I_k(\sigma)$ satisfies $(k+1)I_k(\sigma)+\sigma I_k'(\sigma)=\sigma I_{k-1}(\sigma)$.

Comment: It seems that in general $I_k(\sigma)=R_1(\sigma)+R_2(\sigma){\mathrm{arctan}}\sigma$, where $R_{1,2}$ are rational functions.

Comment: Note that for convergence of the Integral for $I_k$ one needs $l \geq k$.

Comment: @JohannesTrost no such relation is needed https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.53

Comment: Anyway  I'm interested just in the case $l\ge k$.

Comment: @Nemo You are right. Of course.